# Stretching backgrounds in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uiview

I came from android developement and write an app in Swift for iOS
In android I could easily create drawable in xml and put it as a background to any view, so it would stretch as needed as shown on picture. 
As I see it - I need a view to serve as a background and label and imageview child to it. Is there a way to do it without a lot of coding? Please notice that I need answers in Swift if coding is unavoidable

[image]

Comment: You don't need to write a single word. Just add imageview on Storyboard or Xib file what ever you are using, and on imageview set your background image with scale to fill property.

Comment: but I need some text too

Comment: You can Use label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
label.minimumScaleFactor=0.5; scale Factor Will be As per your need.

Comment: @SagarShirbhate thanx, let me try it. But will it stretch background?

Comment: Yes It will Just Fix the width of Background